# Anybody understand why it is that the rigid bodies are not colliding in this scene?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

As always, I thank anyone who might be able to help. I have experienced instances of my having followed the instructions in tutorials perfcctly with the results not having been the same as those achieved in the videos, and so it is no surprise that when extrapolating and applying the general principles to my own models, especially when rigid body collision is concerned, I am also experiencing aberrant results. I did all that I have heard and read to do to set up the one object as the catalyst in the collision, and also have taken the steps that I am aware of to cause the shards to respond to it, but as usual, nothing is happening. I have another slightly different version of this model in which the shards are just collapsing from the beginning of the animation despite the fact that they are deactivated, so I don't know what the issue is.

As shown below, the sphere doesn't break the door when colliding with it, it just pass through it.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

A Simple .blend file provided and can be downloaded from here: [image]

Comment: providing a ~100MB file is not a good thing to provide, you should simplify your file and add screenshot of your problem to make it easier for people here to download and investigate your problem.

Comment: Right. I just don't want to tamper with it and possibly wind up saving things I didn't intend to or eliminating a possible cause of the problem by simplifying the file.

Comment: Here's a series of screenshots https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3iO3keGWrXMNW5tc1R2ajhYTm8

Comment: The door is comprised of shards, they are all set to start deactivated, their scale and rotation is applied, and they are set to active. The sphere is also a rigid body with the Animated box checked.

Comment: As mentioned before, you are not doing yourself any favour by uploading a 100mb file, you need to upload a simpler file so people can help you. I recommend delete everything in the scene except the door and sphere (which is the actually the problem) then once someone help you solve it, you can then apply the change in your original big file.

Comment: This is what I was trying to do in the scene, but it still doesn't work in the scene with all the settings being the same as in these simple scenes. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3iO3keGWrXMWnQ4QVZkRUt4Tk0   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3iO3keGWrXMX1pCMWpLMEx0SlU

Comment: I've downloaded your file and simplified your file and edited your question. Hopefully someone will be able to help

Comment: Well, thank you very much! I have made a stripped down version of the file which retains elements which may be essential to figuring out the problem and solution, the problem now being that the door collapses at the start of the animation regardless of my having done all that is described in tutorials I have watched as the necessary steps to prevent this. The problem may be with intersections between the hardware and door, but what good would smashing a door be if the door doesn't actually look like a door with knobs, hinges, etc.? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3iO3keGWrXMUDVoWGZuZWZfTk0

Comment: ..Of course, I made a different door, one piece with the internal material option in cell fracture instead of three layers, and actually used the same cell fracturing method for this one as I used for the doors in those videos.

Comment: that's good, so is it working now?

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner, and no, it is continuing to collapse unless it is made non-colliding. I was referring to the one in the file linked in my second-to-last comment with the door frame, hardware, walls, floorboards, etc.

Comment: may be try posting a thread at https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?42-Particles-and-Physics-Simulations hopefully someone will be able to help you. And use the simple file I used in your question so that the file size doesn't turn off people from trying to help you.

Comment: Well, the one I uploaded recently is only a few megabytes larger than yours, and it contains the cell fractured door and everything that might be interacting with it.

Comment: So can you upload it to stack-exchange and edit the question and put it instead of mine? I can do it for you if you don't know how, but I have no access to a pc right now, but I can do it later. Hopefully someone will be able to help. I'd still suggest posting it on blenderartists

Comment: Well, thank you very much for volunteering to do that, and I very much appreciate all your help with this, but I'll do that myself at some point if it turns out it's totally necessary. Thanks again!

Comment: I just uploaded your modified file and edited the question, changes to the question should appear soon. I hope someone will be able to help you. you are welcome.